# asp.net 1.0 website that is getting a 'does not allow partially trusted callers' error during sendmail

Tags: email, medium-trust

I have an old asp.net 1.0 website that throws an error during the sending of email.

The error:

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

Is there a way to fix this without recompiling or changing code?

host doesnt' allow fulltrust.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust the security policy to grant the calling assembly Full trust (Admin tools -> .Net Configuration -> Runtime Security policy)

But then you will have the same problem with the assembly you just granted the full trust. Also granting it full trust can potentially create a security hole

Comment: host doesn't allow fulltrust, that's the issue.

Comment: To resolve your problem you have either change the security settings or change the code. If security cannot be changed than your only option is to change the code so that there will be no references to the objects from the picky assemblies